# How to use JQuery plugin inside AngularJS app?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins

How to use the following JQuery plugin inside my AngularJS app to display pdf saved in database?

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/VX7EN

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use, it's to create **directive** and put your jquery plugin there.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a new directive with an isolated scope. Then in your controller call the jQuery plugin.. And if you need to update the content/data/display  of your directive using some jQuery event or callback, just call `$apply`  (Btw maybe you can just wrote the behavior/feature of that jQuery plugin in plain js/angular and get rid of jQuery dependency)

Or if the problem is create the modal window just can use a well know and tested directive https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: how can I write this features in plain angularJs ?! I'm new with AngularJs

Comment: What is the thing you can't do? show the pdf? (retrieve it) o create the modal?

Comment: Thank you msdark, I did it already :) thank you again for your help